# Order by post meta value gets random results

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I want to order a custom post type  by  post meta field. This query works fine partially and load results. The problem is that  the order of results vary at each time this query is executed. I have found some duplicates also in last few pages. Can you please help me figure out what sort of thing going there?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'estate_agent' AND
((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND  
(wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'package_id') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

[image]

**Updated**
Actually I 'm using the Wordpress way for running above query. The above is the raw query output from Wordpress debug plugin. I'm really sorry for the confusion. This is what I have tried.

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'estate_agent',
                'post_status'     => 'publish',
                'meta_key' => 'package_id',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'paged' => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'cache_results' => false,
               );

            $agent_selection = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using SQL when there is our Codex!

Use this code snippet instead-

```
function pre_change_query( $wp_query ) {

        $wp_query->set('meta_key', 'package_id');
        $wp_query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
        $wp_query->set('order', 'DESC'); // or 'ASC'

}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'pre_change_query');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'estate_agent',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10
);

$my_custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

See Codex for details: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Did you test my code?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a custom query to database when you can do it using core WordPress feature, [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). This will get you started. You can set the order to 'ASC' or 'DESC' depending on your requirement.

```
$agents = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'      => 'estate_agent',
        'meta_key'       => 'package_id',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'          => 'DESC'
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
    )
);

if ( $agents->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $agents->have_posts() ) {
        $agents->the_post();

        // Do your stuffs for each Agents here, Like:
        printf( esc_html__( 'Package ID: %1$s', 'textdomain' ), get_post_meta ( get_the_ID(), 'package_id', true ) );

    }
} else {

    // No Agents Found

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: @RajithaBandara Your code looks good to me. However, there's no need to add `paged` param as WordPress do the pagination by default. Try my code and see if that works for you.